# Clojure: incanter.stats Linear Regression Model Not Working

Tags: clojure, incanter

I am following the linear regression example [here](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/wiki/statistics-examples#wiki-linreg)

```
(use '(incanter core stats datasets))
(def plant-growth (to-matrix (get-dataset :plant-growth) :dummies true))
(def y (sel plant-growth :cols 0))
(def x (sel plant-growth :cols [1 2]))
(def lm (linear-model y x))
```

However I get this error:

```
=> (def lm (linear-model y x))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number clojure.lang.Numbers.lt (Numbers.java:219)
```

What is going on here?

Update: Neither does this example from the latest [1.4.1 (Stable) docs](http://liebke.github.io/incanter/stats-api.html#incanter.stats/linear-model):

```
(use '(incanter core stats datasets charts))
(def iris (to-matrix (get-dataset :iris) :dummies true))
(def y (sel iris :cols 0))
(def x (sel iris :cols (range 1 6)))
(def iris-lm (linear-model y x)) ; with intercept term
```

Output:

```
=>  (def iris-lm (linear-model y x))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.lt (Numbers.java:219)
```

I'm using Clojure 1.5.1 and Incanter 1.4.1.  Is this a bug that needs fixing?  Where can I find authoritative, working examples?

Comment: Tried your code. Same error with Clojure 1.4.0 and Incanter 1.4.0.

Comment: I just tried latest Incanter snapshot & it works without errors...

Comment: @leonid, thanks for taking the time to reproduce.  @alex, it appears the version on clojars contains the error.  my project.clj contains:     ` :dependencies [
        [org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
        [incanter "1.4.1"]]`

Comment: I've just released Incanter 1.5.0 - can you try it please?

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, fixed in Incanter 1.5.0.